# how to replicate between two databases in the same couchdb instance

Tags: curl, couchdb

i am trying to replicate data between two local database instance

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/How_to_replicate_a_database

As per the above link, i created two couchdb instance and trying to test whether they are running using curl

$curl http://localhost:5001/

but it is giving output a html page saying connection refused (111) and i can get the result json in browser

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're not using the init script to start the two instances. You'll need to call the couchdb bin file directly and tell it which local.ini file to use. For example, `sudo /usr/local/bin/couchdb -a /path/to/other/local.ini`

I suggest this because the "refused connection" error most likely means that CouchDB isn't listening on that port.